# Connect a Mini Air Pump Motor to Raspberry Pi (3 or zero)

Tags: pi-zero

I have a Raspberry Pi (3 or zero) and I wish to connect to it a Mini Air Pump Motor (e.g., http://www.dx.com/p/szf301-mini-water-pump-motor-white-silver-black-1-25v-6v-206278#.WYRhaelLdaQ ) so I can use it as a controlled aquarium pump.  How can I do it? Where I can find more information and suitable component? Is there a USB solution? Any idea will help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this and any of them are valid. It ultimately depends on how much time and money you want to put into it.

Use a transistor/MOSFET/relay and build a circuit connecting the fan to the Collector and Emitter with a current limiting resistor, then have the Pi connected to the base on one of its GPIO pins. You would then need to use Python or Node-Red to control the on-off state of the pump. Further, you could also control the speed of the pump using a PWM type signal. Here's a quick example that would help out: http://www.davidhunt.ie/howto-switching-onoff-a-dc-motor-with-a-raspberry-pi/

If you aren't too up and up with creating circuits and the like, Sparkfun.com and Adafruit.com are good websites to purchase hobby electronics as well as many tutorials. @Matsk suggestion for Adafruits tutorial is very applicable.

Another thing you could do use a common 110VAC fish store air pump with a relay, something like this: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2935

Best of luck, welcome to mechatronics!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a relay solution if you are seeking a On/Off . And relays that can be added to a Raspberry is simplest found by searching for *raspberry pi hat relay*.

If you want to control it with direction and speed a solution like this would be preferred, example: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-dc-and-stepper-motor-hat-for-raspberry-pi/using-dc-motors

Answer (score 0):

A simple method would be to buy a Raspberry Pi compatible relay module.  These can be switched on and off from a Pi GPIO.  You connect the power line for the pump in series with the relay.  This allows on/off control of the pump.

A better method would be to buy a suitable transistor.  These can be rapidly switched on and off from a Pi GPIO.  You connect the power line for the pump in series with the transistor.  This allows on/off and PWM control of the pump.  Using PWM would allow you to vary the pump speed.